# How to read and create a list of all the feed in a document on firestore and create a list which replaces the list of titles in the following code

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

i want to connect my flutter app to firestore database so that i can get the new headings from my database directly instead of reading the coded string list (named as -'title' here in the code), i am a newbie to flutter and dart  having a hard time figuring this out.

```
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Image.asset(images[i], fit: BoxFit.cover),
                      Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                  horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 8.0),
                              child: Text(title[i], // the list i want to replace with firestore data
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontSize: 25.0,
                                      fontFamily: "SF-Pro-Text-Regular")),
                            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) provided in flutter

Example:

```
return Container(
      child: FutureBuilder<dynamic>(
        future: firestore.fetchAll(), // your async function for data fetching
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }

          final data = snapshot.data; // all your data from firestore
          return ListView(// widget code here...);
```